# CallTo does not work in a loop

Tags: fakeiteasy

I am trying to create a fake of an object cache class to use in a test, and I am running into strange behavior.

I started with this:

```
IObjectCache objectCache = A.Fake<IObjectCache>();

List<ICachedObject> objects = new List<ICachedObject>();

ICachedObject object1 = A.Fake<ICachedObject>();
A.CallTo(() => object1.Id).Returns(random.Next());
objects.Add(object1);

//Snip: Identical statements for object2 & object3...

A.CallTo(objectCache)
    .Where(call => call.Method.Name == "get_Item")
    //"get_Item" is the generated name for the indexer []
    .WithReturnType<ICachedObject>()
    .WhenArgumentsMatch((int objectId) => objectId.Equals(object1.Id))
    .Returns(object1);

//Snip: Identical statements for object2 & object3...

//The lookup works as expected:
var x = objectCache[object1.Id]; //returns object1
var y = objectCache[object2.Id]; //returns object2
var z = objectCache[object3.Id]; //returns object3
```

After getting that working, I wanted to clean up the test a bit by moving the "CallTo" statements to a loop.  However, when I do that, the fake no longer returns the expected objects.

```
foreach (ICachedObject obj in objects)
{
    A.CallTo(objectCache)
        .Where(call => call.Method.Name == "get_Item")
        //"get_Item" is the generated name for the indexer []
        .WithReturnType<ICachedObject>()
        .WhenArgumentsMatch((int objectId) => objectId.Equals(obj.Id))
        .Returns(obj);
}

//Only the last object "added" works
var x = objectCache[object1.Id]; //returns a new, empty object
var y = objectCache[object2.Id]; //returns a new, empty object
var z = objectCache[object3.Id]; //returns object3
```

I'm wondering if perhaps the arguments to WhenArgumentsMatch & Returns are not evaluated until they are called by the indexer lookup and can only hold one value.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue, but I have a strong suspicion... Are you using C# 4 or earlier? Before C# 5, the loop variable in a `foreach` loop was logically declared *outside* the loop, so if you captured it in a lambda, you were always referring to the same variable. This means that when your lambda `(int objectId) => objectId.Equals(obj.Id)` is evaluated, `obj` always refers to the last item from the list. This behavior was changed in C# 5 so that the loop variable is logically declared *inside* the loop, which prevents this surprising behavior (see [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) from Eric Lippert for details).

If this is indeed the reason for your problem, just make a copy of `obj` in the loop:

```
foreach (ICachedObject obj in objects)
{
    var copy = obj;
    A.CallTo(objectCache)
        .Where(call => call.Method.Name == "get_Item")
        //"get_Item" is the generated name for the indexer []
        .WithReturnType<ICachedObject>()
        .WhenArgumentsMatch((int objectId) => objectId.Equals(copy.Id))
        .Returns(copy);
}
```

By the way, you can configure these calls much more easily:

```
foreach (var obj in objects)
{
    var copy = obj;
    A.CallTo(() => objectCache[copy.Id]).Returns(copy);
}
```

Comment: Nailed it! That was exactly the issue.

Comment: ... Or even `objectCache[copy.Id] = copy;`, if there is a setter for the indexer.

Comment: @BlairConrad indeed, but I assumed the indexer was read-only.